# Two commuted Matrices with degenerate eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have two huge commuted Matrices A and B, each one of them contains a large amount of degenerate eigenvalues. Now I compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A. Since [A,B] = 0, if eigenvalue of A is not degenerate, the eigenvector of A should also be the eigenvector of B. However if some eigenvalues of A are degenerate, after I compute these eigenstates using program numerically, these eigenstates might not be the eigenstates of B.

Now I only want those eigenvectors with one specific eigenvalue(say b, which is a number) of B, then how can I get the eigenstates of B with eigenvalue b in these degenerate eigenstates of A? My purpose is trying to reduced matrix A into the subspace of those states with eigenvalue of B, b.

Comment: I think you mean "commuting matrices".  Do you mean that $AB = BA$?

Comment: For those who don't know: "degenerate" = "repeated"

Comment: I don't understand the actual question at all.  I don't understand " how can I get the eigenstates of B with eigenvalue b in these degenerate eigenstates of A"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Since these repeated eigenstates of A might not be the eigenstates of B (when you do it numerically), then I want to find out what is the eigenstates of B in this subspace spanned by these repeated eigenstates of A. In particular, I want those eigenstates with eigenvalue b of B.

Comment: So given a specific eigenvalue $b$ of $B$, you're looking for eigenstates for $B$ (associated with $B$) that are also eigenstates of $A$.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Here is the problem, for example, I am solving the eigenstates of A, get |a_01> and |a_02>, which has the same eigenvalue a. |a_01> and |a_02> can be, for example, |a_01> =  |b1> + |b2>, where |b1> has eigenvalue b1 of B, and |b2> has eigenvalue b2 of B, but they have the same eigenvalue a of A. This is a simple version of this problem. The actual situation can be more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given eigenvalues $a$ of $A$ and $b$ of $B$, you're looking for a vector $x$ such that $Ax = ax$ and $Bx = bx$.  That is, you're looking for a vector $x$ such that $(A - aI)x = (B - bI)x = 0$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix).  In other words, you're looking for a vector $x$ such that
$$
\pmatrix{A - a I\\ B - bI}x = 0
$$
So, it is sufficient to find a basis of the nullspace of the block-matrix $\pmatrix{A - a I\\ B - bI}$.